# Как изменить белый фон новых вкладок в firefox 58?

Tags: firefox

Как изменить белый фон новых вкладок в firefox 58 ?

Answer (score 1):

[Решение на ютюбе](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BnaDi_df1eQ)

1. Введите в адресной строке `about:profiles`
2. Откройте **ROOT Directory** нажав по "Open directory button". **Только не** Local Directory.
3. Создайте папку "chrome" вбив в терминале `mkdir chrome` или правой кнопкой мыши.
4. Откройте эту папку и создайте там css файл с именем "userContent.css"
5. Вставьте этот код в файл "userContent.css" :

   @-moz-document url("about:newtab") {
       body {
           background-color: #000000 !important;
       }
   }
6. Перезапустите ваш браузер вручную либо нажав на кнопку "Restart normally..." по адресу `about:profiles`.

Получите нужный результат ! :)

[Источник](https://superuser.com/questions/1289211/how-to-make-the-aboutnewtab-page-black-or-any-other-color-in-firefox-58)